# JSF - loading a xhtml from outside

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Hey I'm beginning my journey with JSF and Java i have question in this subject.

Question:

Is it possible to load and use xhtml that is not actually stored inside a war file but somewhere outside? I'd like to store it in a database or eventually on a FTP server. Can i register it as a resource in JSF.

Comment: Why you'd want to do that?

Comment: I am guessing this is part of a grand scheme of creating a content management system on top of JSF. It's not the tool for that job if I'm correct. In any case if you must persist it would greatly benefit you to google "java facelets load from database", you are not the first person to ask this question.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure about the Database part but there are some interesting approaches for connecting to NAS drives (which can serve as FTP location also).

1. If you are deploying as open WAR, Using links in the underlying OS allow you to map a location from the open directory to a mapped drive (NAS location) where you can FTP your xhtml pages.
2. If you are deploying on Weblogic (I am sure others have a similar feature) you can use the  [option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/weblogic_xml.html) in the web.xml  to redirect all requests to an underlying NAS location.

I have used both the above approaches successfully with JSP and HTML so don't see any challenges with xhtml.